# What is this technic pin?

Tags: technic, part-identification

In  [Kooberz' video,](https://youtu.be/BPCCsYUgj2I?t=17) he uses a techinc pin that looks like
[image]
What is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BrickLink says that it's called the  [*"Pin with Friction Ridges Lengthwise WITH Center Slots."*](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=2780#T=C)

However it may also be the [*"Pin with Friction Ridges Lengthwise WITHOUT Center Slots."*](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=4459#T=C)

[image]